# Using C code in c#

Tags: c#

When i googled to find the way to change the window style i could find the code in "C" language
How can i use the snippet below in my c# application, so that i can hide the Title Bar of external application ? I have not used "C" before..

```
    //Finds a window by class name
[DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

//Sets a window to be a child window of another window
[DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
public static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

//Sets window attributes
[DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
public static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

//Gets window attributes
[DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
public static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

//assorted constants needed
public static int GWL_STYLE = -16;
public static int WS_CHILD = 0x40000000; //child window
public static int WS_BORDER = 0x00800000; //window with border
public static int WS_DLGFRAME = 0x00400000; //window with double border but no title
public static int WS_CAPTION= WS_BORDER | WS_DLGFRAME; //window with a title bar

/*
 This function sets the parent of the window with class
 ClassClass to the form/control the method is in.
*/
public void Reparent()
{
//get handle of parent form (.net property)
IntPtr par = this.Handle;
//get handle of child form (win32)
IntPtr child = FindWindow("ClassClass", null);
//set parent of child form
SetParent(child, par);
//get current window style of child form
int style = GetWindowLong(child, GWL_STYLE);

//take current window style and remove WS_CAPTION from it
SetWindowLong(child, GWL_STYLE, (style & ~WS_CAPTION));
}
```

Comment: You want to change a windows style? - is this for your application or all windows? Winforms, ASP, WPF?
I note that this is the same as another post that you have.

Comment: @ChrisBD, i want to hide the Title bar of an application [Third party] which has only one form. And this application is started by my c# windows application. It's not for all windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a P/Invoke exprert, but looking at: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll/SetWindowLong.html I guess you can call SetWindowLong to change window style without reparent.

For the window search you can try this:

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad.exe");
foreach (Process p in processes)
{
    IntPtr pFoundWindow = p.MainWindowHandle;
    // now you have the window handle
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The snippet you have posted is in C#, not in C. You should be able to just add that code to your form and call the `Reparent` method. (Assuming you are using `WinForms`)

Note that the `Reparent` method will not only change the window style, but will also attempt to parent the window as a child of your window.

Comment: How can i pass the application name to this function. Say "NotePad.exe", so that it removes the title bar of notepad.
Also help me to avoid the Reparent. Thanks.

Comment: @karthik you need to change the `FindWindow` (which looks up a window by its class) with the @digEmAll way of finding the main window for particular process.