# How to control third party apps by winforms c# app?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winform application that works with/for third party exes. These third party apps do not have any api or command line parameters.  Is it possible to control third party apps from winform application using c#.

All I need is:-

- Open third party exe within winform app. Winform will work as a container.
- let the users uses thirdy party apps
- then Exit/End/Close third party exe by winform app.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `Winform will work as a container` what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this for many apps by re-parenting. See [here for starters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333171).

I mentioned many apps which implies "not all." For example, the Windows calculator will give you headaches if you try to switch modes (Standard, Scientific etc.) because each mode change creates a new window. MS Word also has a complex windowing scheme. But things like Notepad and other straightforward apps will work.

So you need to get/start the process, get the process' window handle and the set the parent to be your application's window.

Here's another usful link for [getting a process' window handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832236).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use  `Process.Start`

But the application won't work as container.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx

Process.Start return `system.diagnostics.process` object which can be used to stop it

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process